# Как установить Apache Coyote?

Tags: java

Мне нужно установить сервлет Tomcat-Coyote, я могу это сделать через maven? Или нужны дополнительные настройки? Подскажите как его подключить. Спасибо.

Comment: Coyote - это часть сервера Tomcat. если вы поставите Tomcat, то в нем уже будет Coyote. опишите задачу которую вы решаете.

Comment: Tomcat server не могу добавить в intellij.
почему не отображается tomcat server в configuration добавил в Maven project depend скачал бинарник добавил в папку intellig , все ровно не работает не отображается . какие есть еще варианты ?

Comment: а какая у вас версия IDEA?

Comment: 2017- 1.1 последняя версия

Comment: community edition?

Comment: михаил , только не говорите что можно использовать apache server только на ultimate

Comment: михаил , только не говорите что можно использовать apache server только на ultimate

Comment: а я уже так привык к intelliJ(

Comment: обновите свой вопрос. добавьте всю информацию. использовать сервер можно.